# MVC select list optiongroup value show on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, select, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 project. And I am using select list with optgroup. Razor Codes below,

```
<select name="filters" id="searchable"  multiple="multiple">
    @foreach (var item in Model.FCategories)
    {
         <optgroup label="@item.FilterCategoryName">
         @{
             var item1 = item;
         }
         @foreach (var filtre in Model.Filters.Where(m => m.FilterCategoryID == item1.FilterCategoryID))
         {
             <option value="@filtre.FilterID">@filtre.FilterName</option>
         }
         </optgroup>
    }
</select>
```

And My Model like this,

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Boş Olamaz")]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Boş Olamaz")]
public string Seo { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<FCategory> FCategories { get; set; }
```

I see filter value with int?. But I cant see optgroup value.... My controller Like this below;

```
public ActionResult AddToCategory()
{
    var fcat = _otherRepository.GetFCategories().ToList();
    var filter = _otherRepository.GetFilters().ToList();
    var modelim = new AdminCategoryViewModel
        {
            Filters = filter,
            FCategories = fcat
        };
    return View(modelim);       
}

[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult AddToCategory(string seo, string name,????????? filters)
{//......}
```

How can I show and take optgroup value on my controller?

Comment: Are you trying to receive both selected option ID and `optiongroup` name it belongs to?

Comment: I cant use optiongroup. Because I am using jquery multiselect list.